# D3 - why is this sort function not updating all the elements in its selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a D3 visualiation that [sorts circle elements (each circle is a planet)](http://bl.ocks.org/radiocontrolled/477a2edb7d0b33ebd2b8). There is a visualise function that creates a circle for each planet like this:

```
<g class="planet">
   <circle class="Mercury" r="1.6264266666666667" cy="90" cx="50" fill="#333">
</g>
<g class="planet">
   <circle class="Venus" r="4.034393333333334" cy="90" cx="198.5" fill="#333">
</g>
<g class="planet">
   <circle class="Earth" r="4.252066666666667" cy="90" cx="347" fill="#333">
</g>
...
```

That same function creates labels for each planet.

I have written a second function, sort, which puts the planets/circles in descending or ascending order.

```
    var sort = function(){

        planets
            .sort(function(a, b) {
                if(orderOfAppearance){
                    return d3.descending(a["Equatorial radius (KM)"], b["Equatorial radius (KM)"]);     
                }
                else{
                    return d3.ascending(a["Mean distance from Sun (AU)"], b["Mean distance from Sun (AU)"]);    
                }


            })
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .attr("cx", function(d,i){
                return ((width * 0.99) / radiuses.length) * i + 50; 
            });
            // other stuff... 
    }
```

The sort function does order the circles correctly (i.e. it is visually correct), but when I inspect the DOM I see that after sort is called all of the circles are appended to the first g element like this, with the other 7 g elements emptied:

```
<g class="planet">
 <circle class="Jupiter" r="47.661786666666664" cy="90" cx="50" fill="#333">
 <circle class="Saturn" r="40.17809333333334" cy="90" cx="198.5" fill="#333">
 <circle class="Uranus" r="17.03816666666667" cy="90" cx="347" fill="#333">
 <circle class="Neptune" r="16.510906666666667" cy="90" cx="495.5" fill="#333">
 ...
 <circle class="Mercury" r="1.6264266666666667" cy="90" cx="1089.5" fill="#333">
</g>
<g class="planet"></g>
<g class="planet"></g>
...
```

Why is my sort function just choosing the first g element as opposed to all g elements in the selection? planets is a selectAll("circle") selection.

I've put everything up in a [gist here](http://bl.ocks.org/radiocontrolled/477a2edb7d0b33ebd2b8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `planets` selection is actually the array of `circle` elements, not `g` elements. To fix this, make sure the variable `planets` is assigned the `g` elements and then append the `circles` afterword. In your sort function, you'll need to update to sort the `g` elements, and then update the `circle` within each.

```
planets = solarSystem.selectAll("g.planet")
    .data(planetaryData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("planet", true);

planets.append("circle")
    .attr({ ...


var sort = function(){

    planets
    .sort(function(a, b) {
          if(orderOfAppearance){
          return d3.descending(a["Equatorial radius (KM)"], b["Equatorial radius (KM)"]);
          }
          else{
          return d3.ascending(a["Mean distance from Sun (AU)"], b["Mean distance from Sun (AU)"]);
          }


          })
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .select("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i){ ...
```